# How do I tell Typescript it's ok to use a string type instead of `#${string}`?

Tags: typescript, discord.js

I'm using Discord.JS in Typescript and they pull this annoying thing where running `setColor` on an embed requires it to be color resolvable or a `#${string}` type.

I have a function which utilizes creating hex codes from one `#RRGGBB` code to the other `#RRGGBB` code, so it makes an array of hex codes on startup. It is known as `string[]`.

When I pick a random item from it, Typescript tells me it MUST be a `Discord.ColorResolvable` type.

Can I just force it down Discord.JS's throat that `string` is good enough?

Comment: Might be interesting https://catchts.com/hex-validation

Comment: Just change the return type of the function to `\`#${string}\`[]`

Answer (score 3):

## Option 1: "Force it down its throat"

You could "force it down its throat" using a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) as @HolgerJeromin mentions.

```
const discordColor = stringValue as Discord.ColorResolvable;
```

or

```
const discordColorArray = arrayValue as Discord.ColorResolvable[];
```

## Option 2: Change the return type of the function that makes the array

Change the return type of your function by defining the array to be of the required type:

```
`#${string}`[]
```

## Option 3: Use a type predicate (a.k.a. typeguard)

By using a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) you could convert any `string` to a color in a safe way.

```
const isDiscordColor = (color: string): color is Discord.ColorResolvable => {
  // Make this check as complex as you want it to be (e.g. checking length or a regex pattern)
  return color.startsWith("#");
}
```

Comment: Your last option generates the following error: `A type predicate's type must be assignable to its parameter's type. Type 'ColorResolvable' is not assignable to type 'string'. Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.`

Answer (score 2):

you could use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions):

```
discordAPI.setColor(yourString[2] as Discord.ColorResolvable)
```